# vue js v-model re render the list and make typing extremely slow

Tags: vue.js

I am developing a chat application. I am using iview ui textarea for the input. When chat list grows, It becomes impossible to type new word. New word takes min to appear in the textarea. I am using v-model to take the input value..

```
<Input @on-enter="sendMsg" class="_chatBox_textarea_textarea" v-model="chatObj.msg" :autosize="{minRows: 1,maxRows: 5}" type="textarea" placeholder="Write a message...">
</Input>
```

I also tried with `v-model.lazy` but still slow..

Comment: this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811786/prevent-vue-js-re-rendering-child-components/69813308#69813308